# TableView returns null (0) when selecting row

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I have a TableView control which I've sectioned/grouped. However this has now broken the code which determines the item I've selected in the Table.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    /*
     When a row is selected, set the detail view controller's detail item to the item associated with the selected row.
     */
    //detailViewController.detailItem = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row %d", indexPath.row];
    if (_delegate != nil) {
        Condition *condition = (Condition *) [_conditions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [_delegate conditionSelectionChanged:condition];
    }
}
```

My sample data currently has 6 sections, the first one contains two items with all the rest containing one. If I select the second item in the first section, the details view updates fine, any other selection always shows the first item in the first section (item 0).

I'm assuming this is because indexPath.row is returning 0 for the other sections as it's the first item in that section, which is then causing the first object from my array to be chosen.

How do I fix my code to ensure the correct item is selected? Everything else works fine other than this.

**cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    // Dequeue or create a cell of the appropriate type.
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    //get the letter in the current section
    NSString *alphabet = [conditionIndex objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];

    //get all conditions beginning with the letter
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name beginswith[c] %@", alphabet];
    NSArray *conditionsGrouped = [_conditions filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    if ([conditionsGrouped count] > 0) {
        Condition *condition = [conditionsGrouped objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = condition.name;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by following the answer at this post: 
[UITableView Problem with Sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046122/uitableview-problem-with-sections)

Answer (score 2):

You should take into account indexPath.section, as well.

You should create a bi-dimensional _conditions array, indexed by section and then by row.

Comment: Thanks for that Ciprian. Can you give me some idea were to begin or point me towards a tutorial or sample, I'm learning this as I go along?

Comment: There's no tutorial for your particular need. How did you implement cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: I've added that code to my question above. Thanks. This also appears to be causing issues with searching as only items from the first section are ever returned.

Comment: This was the problem: you were displaying the rows by section, using the first letter, and you were not doing the same thing for selection.